# Does $\int_{2018}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\mathrm dx$ converge / diverge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Determine if the following integral absolutly converges, conditionaly converges or diverges.

$$
\int_{2018}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\mathrm dx
$$

I thought maybe to try dirichle:

$$
f(x) = x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x, g(x) = \cos x
$$

But $f(x)$ is not monotonic

I thought to look at the absolute value:

$$
\left|\frac{\cos x}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\right|\le \frac{1}{|x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x|}
$$

But i dont see where to go from here.

I dont have an idea, stuck, can you help?

Comment: Subtract $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ from the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

Use integration by parts with $dv=\cos(x)\,dx$:
$$
\int_{2018}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (x)}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\,dx
$$
$$
= \left. \frac{\sin (x)}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\right|_{2018}^{\infty}+\int_{2018}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{3}\sin^2(x)  x^{-2/3} + x^{1/3} \sin(2x) + 1}{(x + x^{1/3} \sin^2(x))^2}\,dx
$$The boundary term is finite and the integrand in the new integral is $O(x^{-5/3})$, which is improperly integrable. So the integral converges, but not absolutely. To see this, note:
$$
\int_{2018}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\cos (x)}{x + x^{1/3}\sin^2x}\right|\,dx
$$
$$
>\int_{2018}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\cos (x)}{10x}\right|\,dx
$$
$$
>\frac{1}{10}\int_{643\pi}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\cos (x)}{x}\right|\,dx
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{n=643}^{\infty}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \left|\frac{\cos (x)}{x}\right|\,dx
$$
$$
>\frac{1}{10}\sum_{n=643}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \left|{\cos (x)}\right|\,dx
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{5\pi}\sum_{n=643}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=\infty
$$

Comment: I didnt understand how you concluded that the new integral in the integration by parts, converges.

Comment: If $a>0,p>1$, $\int_a^{\infty} x^{-p}\,dx$ converges. The denominator is bounded by $x^2$ and some constants and the numerator is bounded by $x^{1/3}$ and some constants, leaving the integrand looking like $x^{-5/3}$.